# run flask and golang server in docker

Tags: python, docker, go, dockerfile

I am trying to run a go web server and a flask server in the same docker container. I have 1 Docker file to build the flask app. How can I update the Dockerfile to build a container to run both python and golang.

ProjectFolder

- pyfolder
  /app.py,
  Dockerfile
- main.go

main.go

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net/http"
)

func handler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    fmt.Println("func called")
}

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", handler)
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil))
}
```

app.py

```
from flask import Flask
import os

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return "Flask inside Docker!!"


if __name__ == "__main__":
    port = int(os.environ.get("PORT", 5000))
    app.run(debug=True,host='0.0.0.0',port=port)
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.6

COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
ENTRYPOINT ["python"]
CMD ["app.py"]
```

Comment: You need to install golang in the python image or python in a golang image. That said, its a big anti pattern. Consider running each one in their own container.

Answer (score 2):

Since you have two separate programs, you would typically run these in two containers, with two separate images.  In both cases you can use a basic Dockerfile for their respective languages:

```sh
# pyfolder/Dockerfile
FROM python:3.6
WORKDIR /app
COPY requirements.txt .
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt .
COPY . .
EXPOSE 5000
CMD ["./app.py"]
```

```sh
# ./Dockerfile
FROM golang:1.16-alpine AS build
COPY go.mod go.sum .
RUN go mod download
COPY main.go .
RUN go build -o main main.go

FROM alpine
COPY --from=build /go/main /usr/bin/main
EXPOSE 8080
CMD ["main"]
```

You don't discuss at all why you have two containers or how they communicate.  You'll frequently want containers to have no local state at all if they can manage it, and communicate only over network interfaces like HTTP.  This means you'll need some way to configure the network address one service uses to call another, since it will be different running in a local development environment vs. running in containers (vs. deployed to the cloud, vs. running in Kubernetes, vs....)  An environment variable would be a typical approach; say the Go code needs to call the Python code:

```golang
url := os.Getenv("PYAPP_URL")
if url == "" {
        url = "http://localhost:8080"
}
resp, err := http.Get(url)
```

A typical tool to run multiple containers together would be [Docker Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/).  It's not the only tool, but it's a standard part of the Docker ecosystem and it's simpler than many of the alternatives.  You'd write a YAML file describing the two containers:

```yaml
version: '3.8'
services:
  pyapp:
    build: ./pyfolder
  server:
    build: . # (the directory containing the Go code and its Dockerfile)
    environment:
      - PYAPP_URL=http://pyapp:5000
    ports:
      - '8080:8080'
    depends_on:
      - pyapp
```

Running `docker-compose up --build` will build the two images and start the two containers.

Comment: ++ where the container runs is an oft overlooked component of deciding how to build your images. Say you were using k8s you could take this approach and bundle both containers in the same *pod* -- this way both containers would be available to each other on localhost. you'd define an port mapping for the pod that exposes one (or both of them) on different ports to the other pods running in k8s

Comment: In Kubernetes, you would generally run these two containers in separate Deployments, with a separate Service for each, and they'd be able to use the Services' names as host names; two containers in a single Pod isn't usually a best practice.

Comment: absolutely could != should.

Answer (score -1):

You should be able to accomplish this using a multistage build in your Dockerfile.

First, move the Dockerfile to the root directory next to the main.go.

Next, modify your Dockerfile to

```
# grab the golang image
FROM golang:1.16
WORKDIR .
RUN go build -o app .

# python portion
FROM python:3.6
WORKDIR /app
# copy the go binary from stage 0
COPY --from=0 app ./
# start the go binary
CMD ["sh", "app"]
# start python
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
ENTRYPOINT ["python"]
CMD ["app.py"]
```

I do think The Fool is correct in suggesting to separate these into two different containers. I would look into docker-compose instead of using a multi-stage build for this use.

[Docker Multistage Build Reference](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/)

Comment: If you build go in muti staging you should statically link your dependencies. Especially for a web server this is likely required. Something like this as build flag `-ldflags '-linkmode external -w -extldflags "-static"'`.

Comment: You can't have two `CMD`s in the same image (or, more correctly, only the last one has an effect).  The `ENTRYPOINT ["python"]` isn't a great pattern and makes it unnecessarily awkward to `docker run your-image ./app` to run the Go binary.

Comment: @TheFool can you share a reference with deeper explanations and examples ? For my own understanding.

Comment: @mh-cbon I dont know any particular guide for this. But I know from experience that I need to do this most of the time when building go in one image and run it in another one.  Some dependencies, especially the network stack are used dynamically, that means go assumes they are in the system you are running your binary on. If those are not in the system, you have a problem. Static linking ensures it will compile those dependencies into the binary itself, as far as I understand.  Maybe this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62817082/how-does-cgo-enabled-affect-dynamic-vs-static-linking

Comment: Its not strictly required. I can image the python image comes with the required dependencies as python is written in c. But, it can happen that you run into trouble. A lot of times when using alpine as final image.

Comment: Here someone is doing it with a scratch image https://gist.github.com/PurpleBooth/ec81bad0a7b56ac767e0da09840f835a
Here, someone wrote an article about it https://weastur.medium.com/go-and-static-linking-1e49d6470293

Comment: yes, now i understand. i agree. `I need to do this most of the time when building go in one image and run it in another one`